# Kivy app can't load video for Xcode Simulator

Tags: xcode, video, kivy, ios-simulator

I wrote a very simple video player as below:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

from kivy.uix.videoplayer import VideoPlayer



class VideoScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(VideoScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)        

        self.video = VideoPlayer(source='test.mp4', state='play',

                               options={'allow_stretch':True,

                                        'eos': 'loop'})

        self.add_widget(self.video)



class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return VideoScreen()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    MyApp().run()
```

It works fine at my Mac machine. Then I packaged it using this command:

```
toolchain create video_test /Users/haipan/python/kivy/video_test/
```

Which generated Xcode project: video_test.xcodeproj in a folder video_test-ios/

Then I double click video_test.xcodeproj, then Xcode launched, then I click the arrow button, then Xcode shows Build Successfully, then its Simulator launched, my app is there,  video player seems there too, but no video playing. The error message as below:

> Got dlopen error on Foundation:
> dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation,
> 0x0001): tried:
> '/Users/haipan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/video_test-drwhokvsjnzjuqblihyyhobprqov/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation'
> (no suchfile), ...

I have tried audio files and pictures, they all loaded fine. But I could never load any video. Did anybody get video running by Kivy app? Does Kivy really support video playing?

Thank you in advance for any help.